# Programmatically read GSM modem port number

Tags: python, port, gsm

Is there any way to read GSM modem port number programmatically using Python, when I connect mobile to Windows XP machine?

Comment: You mean you want the port to which your mobile is connected?

Comment: Yes I mean the port to which my mobile is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I donot know the python syntaxes, just an idea to follow. You can use `SerialPort.GetPortNames();` to get the list of available ports in your system.

And then send an `AT` command to each port. Which ever port responds with an `OK` , it means that your modem is connected to that port.

Comment: Adding to @Cdeez, in python if you use pyserial you can do something like [this](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html#listing-ports)